# converting c++ to c (cout input function)

Tags: c++, c

```
cout << endl << setprecision(2) << fixed;
```

I don't know how can I write this. I know that `cout`(C++) is `printf`(C)

I think that:

```
printf("%d",setprecision(2));
```

Comment: You cannot do that without creating your own wrapper. C doen't have function to set such default format.

Comment: `cout << endl;` can be written as `putchar('\n'); fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: when I try this that error coming [Error] 'setprecision' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @HasanDamirli _"[Error] 'setprecision' was not declared in this scope"_ Ditch that, you're on the completely wrong track anyways. Read about `printf()` format specifiers.

Comment: `%d` is for integer values. What do you expect that `precision` to do?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to read up on [C printf format specifiers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/format-specifiers-in-c).

In your specific case, if you want to include two decimal places after the period. To do this your number needs to be a float rather than an int, and you need to use the `%.2f` format specifier.

```
printf("%.2f", (float)variable)
```

There are many other format specifiers and modifiers on them. Good studying!

Comment: [Link to more complete documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: Thanks. I felt the link I offered was a little more approachable for someone who is new to it, but it's good to have the more in-depth resource as well.